# python reading lines w/o \n?

Tags: python, file, newline

Would this work on all platforms? i know windows does \r\n, and remember hearing mac does \r while linux did \n. I ran this code on windows so it seems fine, but do any of you know if its cross platform?

```
while 1:
    line = f.readline()
    if line == "":
        break
    line = line[:-1]
    print "\"" + line + "\""
```

Comment: OS X uses \n - it was only the abomination that was "Classic" that did \r.

Comment: Any line ending (including unicode ones) are translated into \n automatically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, there is [universal newline support](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/)

Second: just use `line.strip()`. Use `line.rstrip('\r\n')`, if you want to preserve any whitespace at the beginning or end of the line.

Oh, and

```
print '"%s"' % line
```

or at least

```
print '"' + line + '"'
```

might look a bit nicer.

You can iterate over the lines in a file like this (this will not break on empty lines in the middle of the file like your code):

```
for line in f:
    print '"' + line.strip('\r\n') + '"'
```

If your input file is short enough, you can use the fact that `str.splitlines` throws away the line endings by default:

```
with open('input.txt', 'rU') as f:
    for line in f.read().splitlines():
        print '"%s"' % line
```

Comment: This will strip off all leading and trailing whitespace, not just the line ending.

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead:

```
line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

> line = line[:-1]

A line can have no trailing newline, if it's the last line of a file.

As suggested above, try universal newlines with rstrip().